# How to get the address value of a function in assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly

In gcc assembly code listed below, I want to store the address of function foo to var, how do i do it? Thanks.

```
.text
.globl foo
foo:
/* do something */

.data
.globl var
var:
    .long /* the address of foo */
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
 .long foo
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried but it fails. Actually, I define a main.c in which there is 'extern long var' that I want to use. But the gcc gives an error which says undefined reference to 'var'

Comment: You are exporting foo, not var.